# How to set value of JSpinner to a certain date

Tags: java, swing

I have a `JSpinner` which I add to the `JPanel` I would like to set its time to the :`GregorianCalendar calendar`

```
JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner();
spinner.setModel(model);
pom.add(new JLabel("Date", JLabel.RIGHT));
pom.add(spinner);
```

How to achieve this as I get IllegalValue exceptions.

Comment: You might be using `spinner.setValue()` to set some value. If not then use that. If you are using that then post that code here and also mention what exact error you are getting.

Comment: Also take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105375/how-to-set-value-of-jspinner-from-string. It might help.

Comment: Start by reading the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) for working examples. If you want to display dates then you will need to use a `SpinnerDateModel`.

Comment: @camickr How to display date only, without the time?

Answer (score 0):

One should do:

```
        SpinnerDateModel model = new SpinnerDateModel();
        model.setCalendarField(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);

        JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner();
        spinner.setModel(model);

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        java.sql.Time time = new java.sql.Time(osoba.getDataZatrudnienia().getTime().getTime());
        spinner.setValue(time);
```